# Custom chef recipe to integrate OpsWorks with Route53

Tags: dns, chef-infra, amazon-route53, aws-opsworks

I'd like to add a custom recipe to my OpsWorks stack to create a Route53 DNS record whenever a new instance is started and remove the DNS record whenever it is stopped.

There's a Route53 Chef cookbook that looks like it can do this. It takes the following form:

```
route53_record "create a record" do
  name  "test"
  value "16.8.4.2"
  type  "A"
  zone_id               node[:route53][:zone_id]
  aws_access_key_id     node[:route53][:aws_access_key_id]
  aws_secret_access_key node[:route53][:aws_secret_access_key]
  overwrite true
  action :create
end
```

My question is: is there a way to get the AWS credentials from OpsWorks attributes that this chef recipe requires? What would be the best practice for passing in these credentials? Custom JSON?

Comment: No - you have to supply them. Why would Opsworks expose those credentials for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using IAM Instance Profiles for your servers. This is the best security practice. ( link [aws blog post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/iam-roles-for-ec2-instances-simplified-secure-access-to-aws-service-apis-from-ec2.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20AmazonWebServicesBlog%20%28Amazon%20Web%20Services%20Blog%29)

It will also work with the route53 cookbook. Without specifying the authkey/secretkey pair, you will force the use of the instance profile access details.

Comment: For the second scenario(without custom IAM Profile) The instance default profile must have policies that allow permissions to write to Route53. EC2 needs the default opsworks IAM profile so the opsworks agent can talk back to the Opsworks sevice to close the feedback look. I don't think Route53 policies are included in : arn:aws:iam::youraccountidnumber:instance-profile/aws-opsworks-ec2-role